# Attach DataBase Syntax Error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to attach a DB and can't figure out the syntax.

```
DECLARE @path1 varchar(250)=N'D:\MSSQL\DATA\ProductDB_Temp.mdf';
DECLARE @path2 varchar(250)=N'D:\MSSQL\DATA\ProductDB_Temp_log.ldf';

/* Attach Database */
CREATE DATABASE ProductDB_Temp ON 
( FILENAME = @path1 ) ,
( FILENAME = @path2 )
FOR ATTACH
```

Error message:

> Incorrect syntax near '@path1'. Expecting ID,Integer,Quoted_Id,string
>   or text_lex

if I construct my script like this:

```
DECLARE @path1 varchar(250)=N'D:\MSSQL\DATA\ProductDB_Temp.mdf';
DECLARE @path2 varchar(250)=N'D:\MSSQL\DATA\ProductDB_Temp_log.ldf';

/* Attach Database */
CREATE DATABASE ProductDB_Temp ON 
( FILENAME = N'D:\MSSQL\DATA\ProductDB_Temp.mdf' ) ,
( FILENAME = N'D:\MSSQL\DATA\ProductDB_Temp_log.ldf' )
FOR ATTACH
```

it works but this is not really what I would like to do.

I am trying to avoid using EXEC. any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid dynamic sql? This is easily accomplished using dynamic sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you will be able to create the database this way.

You will need dynamic SQL for that.  Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3397931/2679529) answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use dynamic SQL like below..

```
DECLARE @path1 varchar(250)=N'D:\MSSQL\DATA\ProductDB_Temp.mdf';
DECLARE @path2 varchar(250)=N'D:\MSSQL\DATA\ProductDB_Temp_log.ldf';

/* Attach Database */


declare @sql nvarchar(max)
SET @Sql = 'CREATE DATABASE newdatabase ON
(filename = ' +@path1+'),
(filename = '+@path2+')
FOR ATTACH'

print @sql
```

check output ,in this case  :

```
CREATE DATABASE newdatabase ON
(filename = D:\MSSQL\DATA\ProductDB_Temp.mdf),
(filename = D:\MSSQL\DATA\ProductDB_Temp_log.ldf)
FOR ATTACH
```

finally

```
EXEC(@SQL)
```